# Creating User Accounts with Puppet/Missing ACLs

Tags: macos, command-line, permission, launchd, automation

Currently we use Puppet in my environment to provision a user account seen [here](https://github.com/mozilla-platform-ops/ronin_puppet/blob/71963ec2bdbb5fb027f17bc51bd52167a59393e4/modules/roles_profiles/manifests/profiles/cltbld_user.pp#L14) and [here](https://github.com/mozilla-platform-ops/ronin_puppet/blob/71963ec2bdbb5fb027f17bc51bd52167a59393e4/modules/users/manifests/single_user.pp#L5)

Recently we noticed on macOS 13 that the user account created were missing ACLs. I believe the missing ACLs are why local Launch Agents fail to automatically execute when the user logs in. The Launch Agents work fine using launchctl load as the logged in user.

Creating accounts in the GUI/sysadminctl seem to land the ACLs also.

One approach could be using a case statement in Puppet to differentiate the OS and fire off a command to setup the account when it detects macOS 13, but it will be a much bigger lift due to other automations currently surrounding how that account is provisioned.

Are there any ways to get users created programmatically with more faithful permissions to match the gui method?

Answer (score 2):

The uid being set was 35 or 36. Setting the uid > 501 made login items and launch agents function as expected.

Comment: Excellent finding. This will help others surely. Thanks!